# Squash variable declarations that are declared by the same function

Tags: typescript

I have multiple variables that are all declared by calling the same function (the only difference is a string parameter). Is there an elegant way of sqashing these declarations so there is not so much repetition?

```
  const random = myFunction(param, 'random');
  const something = myFunction(param, 'something');
  const anotherVariable = myFunction(param, 'anotherVariable');
  const andSoOn = myFunction(param, 'andSoOn');
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a small abstraction that would return an object with your variables:

```
const createVars = (fn, common, ...strArgs) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    strArgs.map((key) => {
      return [key, fn(common, key)];
    })
  );
};

// and use it like this

const { random, something, anotherVariable, andSoOn } = createVars(
  this.myFunction,
  param,
  "random",
  "something",
  "anotherVariable",
  "andSoOn"
);
```

I assumed that you want to have the same variable names as the string arguments you are passing inside.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for